# Sending what ASCII symbol is PuTTY's equivalent of Enter key?

Tags: c++, serial-port, putty

(Is it carriage return `\r` like in C++?)

When I type `AT`+`[Enter]` in PuTTY while connected to modem's `COM3` port, I get the expected `OK` response.

But when I use my (tested*) C++  program to send an `AT\r` (and also just `AT`) to the modem, I get no echo, nor any errors saying the sending failed.

**I'll show my code in other question if the problem is not HERE.** I just want to be sure that I didn't *already* make a mistake by sending a `\r` using the `WriteFile` function via `COM3` port.

Should I be sending a `\r` or other symbol to indicate command's end?

.

(*I checked: my program sends and recieves data via connected `COM` ports without problem, even if it has to recieve data *right after* sending data of its own.)

Comment: use `\n` or `\r\n`

Comment: *"I get no echo"* -- Don't confuse "echo" with "response".  Those are two completely different entities.  Regardless of what the Enter key generates (should be `\r`),  *termios* or the terminal emulator program can remap it to other key combinations.  BTW you can manually generate `\n` and `\r` using the `Ctrl` key with the `J` and `M` keys respectively.